# Unexpected type error 5

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So I have this code.

```
public double crossRatio(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
        // To do!
        return ((a-c)(b-d))/((b-c)(a-d));
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

**Compiler error:**

```
/tmp/codecheck.work.RdPtyqdODZ/MathInJava.java:40: error: unexpected type
    return ((a-c)(b-d))/((b-c)(a-d));
              ^
required: class
found:    value
/tmp/codecheck.work.RdPtyqdODZ/MathInJava.java:40: error: unexpected type
    return ((a-c)(b-d))/((b-c)(a-d));<br>
                           ^<br>
required: class
found:    value
```

help please.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing multiplication symbol (*) between your expressions on either side of the "/"

```
((a-c)*(b-d))/((b-c)*(a-d));
```